# I am making a graphing method and the y-Value keeps getting flipped

Tags: java, math, arraylist, methods, graph

So, whenever I input the value '1.0, 0.0' or the values '1.0, 2.0' the graph I have made returns a flipped y-value, and whenever I input the values 1.0, 0.0 the graph is just completely off by 5. This method is meant to take in an arraylist of double values (the coeffecients) in a polynomial, and then solve for y, substituting values from -5 to 5 into the equation. The graph outputs, and the x-values are correct, its just the y-values which are flipped.

So, what have I tried so far? Well, negatating the yVal in 3 different places, negating the xVal in the for loop, separating the for loop, unifying it, using different variables, everything. Nothing has worked and I've spent like 2 hours on it. ATP i think it might be something simple that I just can't see, but I really can't figure out what it is. I also thought it could be my substitution method which was off, but I've tested it a ton and nothing is wrong with it. Test cases: "1.0, 0.0", "1.0, 2.0"
Code:
```

```
public static double sub(ArrayList<Double> currentCoefList, double val) {
    double subbed = 0.0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < currentCoefList.size() - 1; i++) {
        subbed += Math.pow(currentCoefList.get(i) * val, currentCoefList.size() - i - 1);
    }
    subbed = subbed + currentCoefList.get(i);
    return subbed;
}

public static char[][] makesGraph(ArrayList<Double> currentArrayList) {

    int row = 11;
    int col = 11;
    int xVal = -5;
    int yVal = 0;
    int[] ysVal = new int[11];
    char[][] grid = new char[row][col];

    for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < grid[0].length; c++) {
            if (r == 5 && c == 5) {
                grid[r][c] = '+';
            } else if (c == 5) {
                grid[r][c] = '|';
            } else if (r == 5) {
                grid[r][c] = '-';
            } else {
                grid[r][c] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < grid[0].length; i++){
        ysVal[i] = (int) sub(currentArrayList, xVal);
        xVal++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < grid[0].length; i++) {
        yVal = Math.round(ysVal[i]);
        if(yVal < 0)
        {
            yVal = yVal + 5;
        }
        else if (i < row && yVal < col) {
            grid[i][yVal] = '*';
        }
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < grid[0].length; c++) {
            System.out.print(grid[r][c]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    return grid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `sub` method is intended to compute *a*<sub>0</sub>*x*<sup>*n*</sup> + *a*<sub>1</sub>*x*<sup>*n*−1</sup> + … +*a*<sub>*n*−1</sub>*x* + *a*<sub>*n*</sub>; do I have that right? If so, then — that's not what you've implemented. You've put your coefficients *a*<sub>*i*</sub> *inside* the call to `Math.pow`, so you're computing (*a*<sub>*i*</sub>*x*)<sup>*n*−*i*</sup> instead of *a*<sub>*i*</sub>(*x*<sup>*n*−*i*</sup>).

There may be other problems as well; that's just one that jumped out at me while trying to figure out what you're trying to do. Eric Lippert has written a very helpful blog post, ["How to debug small programs"](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), that can help you find and fix them all. :-)